# Outswing exterior door in 6inch wall- did contractor install correctly?

Tags: doors, exterior, construction

We're doing a large addition with 6" walls and the back outswing door doesn't seem right, and a little research indicates there are specific doors/windows for 6" walls but neither our architect, contractor or window/door salesman mentioned it (all new construction here is required to have the thicker walls) and we didn't get those. In addition to the latch dragging across paint the door is also very stiff, I asked our contractor about it and he got a bit defensive and said it was installed correctly, and I wanted to get more information before pushing the issue.

The door is in and trimmed and the exterior stuccoed, we're trying to figure out the best course of action, from living with it to requesting or demanding a fix (and what that should be).

detail of door frame and catch dragging on paint:
[image: detail of door frame and catch dragging on paint]

Comment: Does it drag if you hold the handle in the unlatch position to keep the bolt retracted? You need an extended striker plate all the way to the edge of the trim. This could be a separate strip of metal set into a shallow channel (1/16" or so) chiseled or routed into the door jamb. https://www.taylorsecurity.com/mobile/don-jo-extended-lip-strikes-el-103-el-104-el-125-bs-161-don-jo-extended-strikes/

Comment: It should curl around the edge of the trim so as to smoothly force the bolt to retract when the door is swung shut as one is exiting. It would be annoying to have to turn and grip the door knob every time you leave. Better to have one continuous striker than two pieces like I wrote bove.

Comment: It only drags if extended, thanks for the link, I didn't know those existed. Edit- Yes, a continuous striker is the way to go, although it will need to be 4" deep, which seems like a lot. I don't think the bolt is causing the door to be tight.